# Marketing Cloud - report on dynamic content

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, query

We have just - for the first time - sent an email using dynamic content for one of our commercial clients.

It was quick and easy - we built 15 different content blocks, 1 template, and 1 data extension. Each person in the data extension received one of the 15 versions (based upon academic subjects).

The client has asked for a report so they can see how many people opened each different version, and we have drawn a blank. The version in 'My Tracking' shows an overall view, and the 'Impression Tracking by Job' report shows how many clicks each version got, but I can't find a report that shows us the delivery rate and open rate of *each version*. There must be such a think - what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to determine the combination of content each subscriber receives with AMPScript, store it in an AMPScript variable and and include that variable name as a column in the [**Send Log**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386631&type=1).  Once you've started collecting the data, you can aggregate the tracking data, either from the [**System Data Views**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_using_the_query_activity.htm&type=5) or [**Data Extract of Tracking Data**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5) imported back into Data Extensions.

You can also use [**Impression Regions**](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_impression_tracking.htm&type=5) and the corresponding canned report, but you can't (easily) use dynamic names for your regions.

Comment: Thanks Adam, I'm following the instructions here https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/send_logging/create_a_send_logging_data_extension/ but I don't seem to have the option to choose a 'SendLog' Template.

Comment: Support can enable send logging for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Discover Reports. There are discover reports available in Marketing Cloud [Discover Reports](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/discover/discover_reports/). For your use case you can use Recent Email Send Summary . You can go to Discover Reports from Analytics Builder-Reports. On Right hand side under Report Catalog you can see Discover folder.

Deepak